# Photoshop CS5 - How to assign position and dimensions from one object to another?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, cs5

I am currently updating an old document that I don't recall how I created the first time around. What I would like to do is to take the size and position of an existing object that underwent a free transform when it was placed in the document originally, and perform the same transformation on the new object I am now adding to the document. I am replacing the old one and I want the new one to be identical in size and position to the original. How can I do this in Photoshop CS5?

Answer (score 1):

I'll suggest...manually =)

1. Enable move tool
2. Enable "Show transform controls" (it should show bounding box of objects on layer, layer should be unlocked. If not showing - enable free transform)
3. Enable snapping and show guides and rulers
4. Drag new guides until snapped to bounding box of object (and center if needed)
5. free transform new object using created guides